# How can I fix the run time error (Heap corruption) in my code?

Tags: c++, algorithm, debugging, runtime-error

This is a quicksort code based on the algorithm in the book(neapolitan). the results are true but at the end of debugging it has a run time error and I can't fix it. the error is *heap corruption* please help me to fix or improve it(if it's wrong). thanks for all answers.

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int partition( int *A, int p, int q)
{
    int x = A[p];
    int i = p;
    for (int j = p+1; j <= q; j++)
    {
        if (A[j] <= x)
        {
            i++;
            swap (A[j],A[i]);
        }
    }
    swap (A[i],A[p]);
    return i;
}

void Quick_sort( int *A, int p, int r)
{
    int q;
    if( p<r)
    {
        q = partition(A,p,r);
        Quick_sort( A, p, q-1);
        Quick_sort( A, q+1, r);
    }
}

void main()
{
    int n;
    cout << "How many elements do you want to sort(quicksort)? ";
    cin >> n;
    int *A;
    A = new int [n];
    for (int k=0;k<n;k++)
    {
        cout << "A["<<k<<"]= ";
        cin >> A[k];
    }

    cout << endl;

    Quick_sort(A,1,n);

    cout << "\nsorted array: " <<endl;
    for (int i = 1; i < n+1; i++)
    {
        cout << A[i]<<"\t";
    }
    cout << endl;
    delete A;
}
```

the question is: Why this code has an error? How many errors do you see in this?

Comment: Start examining your program with a debugger.

Comment: Use a different book.  Here are some issues:  "malloc", arrays instead of vectors, "void main()".  Looks like your book was for the C language and changed the I/O to make it look C++.

Comment: the algorithm is based on book. not the code!!!

Comment: at first be sure about your answer then write it.

Comment: I realized that there was no error and the error was PDB file error in visual studio. so the code and algorithm is correct. sorry for all respondents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code should be: `for (int k=1;k<=n;k++)` instead of `for(int k=0;k<n;++k)`
and also change the line: 
`A = new int [n];` with `A = new int [n+1];`
I debug it with no errors!
good luck

Comment: How can I accept your answer? I click on it but its not work!

Comment: When you borrow memory from HDD with new, index of array starts from 0 to n-1. so in the loops I and k are starts from 1 to n and it is a debugging error.

Answer (score 1):

You have a so called "fence post error", where your array indices are off by one.
The lines

```
A =(int *) malloc(n * sizeof(int));
```

and

```
for (int k=1;k<=n;k++)
{
    cout << "A["<<k<<"]= ";
    cin >> A[k];
}
```

propably cause the error, you start the index with 1 instead of 0. The code should be

```
for (int k=0;k<n;++k)
{
    cout << "A["<<k<<"]= ";
    cin >> A[k];
}
```

note that you also have the same error in the second for-loop

Comment: before you answer the question, run the code with new changes you say. I edit the code but it already has the same error.

Comment: @illusionist_yahya before you post condescending comments, think about the answer. This answer is perfectly correct in that it points out a serious error in your code. Probably this was not the only error in your code, but you **still** need to fix this.

Comment: How can I fix this if you know?

Comment: I realized that there was no error and the error was PDB file error in visual studio. so the code and algorithm is correct. sorry for all respondents.